# Spring Boot war deployment with Tomcat8 and ErrorPageFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat8

My application is setup as follow:

- Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE
- Tomcat 8.5
- Deployed as a WAR
- Spring MVC

I am running into an issue with the BasicErrorController.  I've tried multiple methods:

1. No changes to Error Handling methods which should result in default white label error page.  This is working as expected for 404 errors, but not 500 errors.  The page received is the default Tomcat error page.
2. Configure an ErrorViewResolver like snippet below.  This is also resolved for 404 errors as expected. For 500 status codes, it is resolved similar to the above where Tomcat is displaying the default error page.

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorViewResolver implements ErrorViewResolver {

    private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveErrorView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpStatus status, Map < String, Object > model) {
        if (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND == status) {
            logger.error("Error 404 for url " + model.get("path"));
            return new ModelAndView("errors/page-not-found", model);
        } else if (HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR == status) {
            return new ModelAndView("errors/server-error", model);
        }

        return new ModelAndView("errors/server-error", model);
    }

}
```

In looking at the ErrorPageFilter, could this be due to response.sendError(..) forcing Tomcat to handle the error?  This snippet is not hit during a 404 call since it's specific to exception handling.  I also don't see this in the master branch of [Spring Boot for ErrorPageFilter.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/8b1a101cb6082f8c1b96c96ab7943d568d23281d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/ErrorPageFilter.java)

```
private void forwardToErrorPage(String path, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Throwable ex)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
            String message = "Forwarding to error page from request "
                    + getDescription(request) + " due to exception [" + ex.getMessage()
                    + "]";
            logger.error(message, ex);
        }
        setErrorAttributes(request, 500, ex.getMessage());
        request.setAttribute(ERROR_EXCEPTION, ex);
        request.setAttribute(ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE, ex.getClass());
        response.reset();
        response.sendError(500, ex.getMessage());
        request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
        request.removeAttribute(ERROR_EXCEPTION);
        request.removeAttribute(ERROR_EXCEPTION_TYPE);
    }
```

Is there a potential issue with Spring boot 2.0.1?  Or should I upgrade to a different version?  Am I missing a separate configuration?  Any thoughts would be great, thanks.

** Edit, Adding Application and Configuration class **

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/ibatisContext.xml", "classpath:spring/daoContext-latam.xml"})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { ...},
        excludeFilters = { ... }
        )
public class LatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LatApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(LatApplication.class);
    }
}
```

MVC Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    CustomStringToArrayConverter stringToArrayConverter;

    @Autowired
    InterceptorController businessTypeInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new CustomStringToArrayConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(businessTypeInterceptor);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the entry class to your project please? The one with the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

Comment: No problem. I added code to original post.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to eliminate incorrect war deployment. I'm assuming you also have changed the <scope> to provided in your pom.xml. What variable changed in your setup that caused these issues? From your post, you name Spring Boot 2.0.1 but have you previously updated tomcat?

Comment: Correct, <scope> is provided for:   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency> 
I was previously using 1.5 version of Spring Boot.  In an attempt to fix a different issue with error handling on tomcat8 (it was not working at all with war deployment - standalone jar worked fine), I started with upgrading the version of Spring Boot to 2.0.1.